# бот отвечает только на "/start", а при вводе города не отдает инфу, ошибок вроде тоже нет

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, aiogram

```
import os
import datetime
import requests
from aiogram import Bot, types
from aiogram.dispatcher import Dispatcher
from aiogram.utils import executor
import math

bot = Bot(token='my token')
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

@dp.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Привет!\nВ каком городе мне посмотреть погоду?")
@dp.message_handler()
async def get_weather(message: types.Message):
    try:
        response = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?&lang=ru&units=metric&appid=my token")
        data = response.json()
        city = data["name"]
        cur_temp = data["main"]["temp"]
        humidity = data["main"]["humidity"]
        pressure = data["main"]["pressure"]
        wind = data["wind"]["speed"]

        sunrise_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunrise"])
        sunset_timestamp = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunset"])

        # продолжительность дня
        length_of_the_day = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data["sys"]["sunset"]) - datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
            data["sys"]["sunrise"])

    except:

        await message.answer(f"{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')}\n"
        f"Погода в городе: {city}\nТемпература: {cur_temp}°C\n"
        f"Влажность: {humidity}%\nДавление: {math.ceil(pressure / 1.333)} мм.рт.ст\nВетер: {wind} м/с \n"
        f"Восход солнца: {sunrise_timestamp}\nЗакат солнца: {sunset_timestamp}\nПродолжительность дня: {length_of_the_day}\n"
        f"Хорошего дня!"
        )
if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp)
```

Comment: 1. Вы оформили бесплатную подписку через свою карточку?

Comment: 2. В ссылку вы также должны передать координаты, это возможно сделать вот так: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68696289/how-can-aiogram-bot-request-users-location

Comment: А где в блоке try хоть какой-нибудь вывод? Я вижу только в except

Answer (score 0):

у вас нет вывода полученных данных в блоке try

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]